# Ruby on Rails API: computed attribute pattern best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, ruby-on-rails-6

I would like to know the best practice when I need a computed attribute that require a call to the database.

If I have a `Parent` that has many `Child`, how would I render a `children_count` attribute in `ParentController#index` as I don't want to render the children, just the count? what's the best way to do it?

Thank you!

Model:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children

  def children_count
    children.count # Wouldn't it ask the database when I call this method?
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class ParentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    parents = Parent.all

    render json: parents, only: %i[attr1, attr2] # How do I pass children_count?
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe you want to adjust the question if its really about counter cache. Otherwise, other solutions apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`children.count` will call the database, yes; however, it will do it as a SQL count:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "children" WHERE "children"."parent_id" = $1
```

It doesn't actually load all of the child records. A more efficient method is to use a Rails counter_cache for this specific case: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache

Answer (score 5):

The Rails way to avoid additional database queries in a case like this would be to implement a [counter cache](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache).

To do so change

```
belongs_to :parent
```

in `child.rb` to

```
belongs_to :parent, counter_cache: true
```

And add an integer column named `children_count` to your `parents` database table. When there are already records in your database then you should run something like

```
Parent.ids.each { |id| Parent.reset_counters(id) }
```

to fill the `children_count` with the correct number of existing records (for example in the migration in which you add the new column).

Once these preparations are done, Rails will take care of incrementing and decrementing the count automatically when you add or remove children.

Because the `children_count` database column is handled like all other attributes you must remove your custom `children_count` method from your `Parent` class and can still simple call

```
<%= parent.children_count %>
```

in your views. Or you can add it to the list of attributes you want to return as JSON:

```
render json: parents, only: %i[attr1 attr2 children_count]
```